# Linear combination of Random Variables less than Zero and Hoeffding's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be Uniform Random Variables and set
$$X = aX_1 + bX_2, $$

with $a \geq 0$ and $b \leq 0$. I'd like to bound $P(X \leq 0)$ using Hoeffding's inequality. How do I do that?

P.S.: I know we can compute $P(X)$ exactly, but I'd like to use the Hoeffding's inequality here. It seems a very straight forward problem, but I do not know how to solve it...

Thanks!

Comment: The Hoeffding inequality deals with $P(|X - EX|<t)$ for $t>0$. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are centered, then you would like to use $t=0$. Also, note the absolute value -- you don't have it in $P(X\leq 0)$. Or are you looking for a very rough bound?

Comment: Hi! yeah, a rough bound would suffice. I think there is a typo on what you wrote. Didn't you mean $P(|X−EX|>t)$? I was exactly wondering about the case when $P(|X−EX|<t)$ using Hoeffding's inequality.